# Creating a makefile for g++ compiler

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I have some code that everytime I want to compile I have to do the following command in the linux shell (just an example):

```
$g++ -I. -I$SYSTEMC_HOME/include -L. -L$SYSTEMC_HOME/lib-linux64 -o sim helloworld.cpp -lsystemc -lm
```

In this example my source file is `helloworld.cpp` and I want it to be compiled in a folder called `sim` in the same folder where the source file is.

How can I automate this process using `make` or `makefile`. Also having the `make clean` option to remove the created folder if called?

Comment: do you have an attempt at the makefile yet?  if so can you post it

Comment: I would have a look into an automated build-system like CMake instead of using handcrafted makefiles. It tends to get messy, especially if you want to change target environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rename your cpp file to `sim.cpp` this is probably the simplest Makefile

```
CPPFLAGS := -I. -I$(SYSTEMC_HOME)/include
LDFLAGS  := -L. -L$(SYSTEMC_HOME)/lib-linux64
LDLIBS   := -lsystemc -lm

sim:

.PHONY: clean
clean: ; $(RM) sim
```

The implicit rules should handle everything else for you

Answer (score 1):

Easy

```
%.o: %.cpp
     g++ $(YOUR_CXX_FLAGS_HERE) -c $< -o $@

$(YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_HERE): $(YOUR_OBJECTS_HERE)
     g++ $(SOME_LDFLAGS_HERE) $^ -o $@

clean:
     rm $(YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_HERE) $(YOUR_OBJECTS_HERE)

.PHONY: clean
```

There are good tutorials outthere, like [this](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/) one.